# WebView not working when overriding custom WebViewClient methods?

Tags: android, webview

In my app I use a `webview` to load a payment page of a bank. I need to `override` some methods of my custom `WebViewClient` like this:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //do some work
        return true;
    }

});
String postData = "RefId=" + URLEncoder.encode(referenceId);
webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
```

problem is in this state, my `webView` doesn't load the page and instead shows a blank page. But when I remove the overridden method like below, the `webView` loads the payment URL like a charm!

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
String postData = "RefId=" + URLEncoder.encode(referenceId);
webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
```

I need to `override` the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` or other methods of the client object. What is the problem and the workaround?

**UPDATE**
So I tried returning false in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method as  Uma Sankar 
suggests and now it works.

Comment: Have tried returning `false` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function?
As per docs:
> Return True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

Comment: Just tried and yes, now it works. Anyways, thanks for the help.